# Eclipse JUnit view

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am trying to get list of methods so I can run tests separately per method.

Although I have a test case file open I don't see anything in the Junit window. It is empty. Even when I run the tests. Help.

[image]

Comment: The _JUnit_ view shows the test results, not the existing tests. In the Java editor, _Package Explorer_, _Outline_ view or wherever right-click the test method and choose _Run As > JUnit Test_. The results are then displayed in the _JUnit_ view.

Comment: That works, Thank you!